# How to disable RecyclerView Adapter when Recyclerview is Invisible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi I have two recyclerview in my app. I am loading data and fill the recyclerview with it. at bottom i have one button , lets say when user load the app, first recylcerview is visible, now user click on bottom button I am hiding first recyclerview and make second recyclerview visible. so now issue is Toast messages of first recyclerview's adapter is still appears even it is hide state.
I do not want to show Toast messages of first recyclerview when it is hide.

```
            recyclerViewfirst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recyclerViewsecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: There are various options to achieve this, one of them like passing the flag of visibility in adapter and on that flag you can manage toast display.

Comment: You should set empty list rather than the visibility of View

Comment: @KishoreJethava how to do that

Comment: post the code, so we can guide you better

Comment: @KishoreJethava its huge code sir

Comment: @khimji stack will never overflow!!

Comment: set recyclerview adapter to null and then hide your view. make sure you don't attach adapter filled with data while its invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow these steps :

No need for setting visibility for `RecyclerView`.

> 1. Pass Empty `ArrayList` to your adapter and set adapter to `RecyclerView`.

```
    Adapter mAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new Adapter(context, mList);
    recyclerViewsecond.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

> 2. When data is there in `ArrayList` simply notify the adapter.

```
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: thanks but solved it using interface. i created methods and access it as per my flow of application.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass any data for first RecyclerView when you click the button. That is you can display RecyclerView again with empty data.

Answer (score 0):

no needs to hide the recycle view
just reset the adapter with another array list and notify the adapter
then first list data will replace with another list data